# How to insert a new record after successful update of a record in grails

Tags: grails

i am trying to insert a new record into a table when admin approves someones request in grails. What is the right method to achieve this? When admin approves a request a table get updated with a Boolean isapprove true and on success of this insert records in another table.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a service and service method to handle the use case.  That method should

1. Take input and decide whether to do the update
2. Update the record with the `isapprove` variable.
3. Create a new record and insert it.  See [this documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#basicCRUD) for how to do it; it's really easy.

Creating the service and service method ensures that the above steps are transactional, so if one step fails the database is in a consistent state.  Also, it is a nice unit of functionality for testing, so the code will be more maintainable.